# Issue when using std::ws and desyncing streams

Tags: c++, std

I am learning C++ and have run into an issue regarding the use of `std::ws` in the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

    std::string s1 {};
    std::string s2 {};

    std::cout << "Enter s1: ";
    std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, s1);
    std::cout << "Enter s2: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, s2);

    std::cout << "s1: " << s1 << '\n';
    std::cout << "s2: " << s2 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

As is, the code asks for the input to `s1` before the `"Enter s1: "` prompt is shown on the screen. Removing `std::ws` allows the prompt to be printed. Alternatively, removing `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)` also produces the expected behaviour, with or without `std::ws`.

It seems to me that there is some interaction going on between the two functions, but I am not sure why that would be. I have not used any C I/O functions, so I do not see why desyncing streams would cause an issue. Could someone explain?

Comment: `produces the expected behaviour` What is the expected behavior? And when - with or without `std::ws` and with or without `sync_with_stdio`?

Comment: May be this _"...If the synchronization is turned off, the C++ standard streams are allowed to buffer their I/O independently..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio ie `std::cout << "Enter s1: ";` is still in the output buffer and has not been flushed to the console.

Comment: @KamilCuk I meant that the printing is done in the correct order.

Comment: By default, *any* read of `std::cin` should be flushing `std::cout` first. So it shouldn't matter if `std::ws` is used or not. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout: "*Once initialized, std::cout is tie()'d to std::cin and std::wcout is tie()'d to std::wcin, **meaning that any input operation on std::cin executes std::cout.flush() (via std::basic_istream::sentry's constructor)**.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau Something seems to be stopping that behaviour here, hence the question.

Comment: If you are just learning C++ -- learn to stay away from iostreams. I am not joking -- in my 20+ years of experience this library was, is and will be huge PITA and if you can do without it -- do it.